# Doing "mvn clean install" on project with eclipse plugin not generating target directory

Tags: maven, maven-2, eclipse-plugin, jenkins, sonarqube

I have a project which has an Eclipse Plugin. I have put all my source files under "**src**" directory. When i am doing **mvn clean install** on this project, it installs the artifacts in the repository but doesn't create a target folder containing the compiled .class files.

I need the compiled classes because I want to integrate sonar through Jenkins with this project.

As soon as I import this project in eclipse, it creates a bin directory with all the compiled class files.

Thanks

Comment: Could you post the `mvn` command output? At least the last lines

Comment: For a maven project, all Java files need to live in `/src/main/java`

Comment: My Java source files are under src/

Comment: If your sources are not in src/main/java, you have to help Maven find them :<build>
<sourcedirectory>src/</sourcedirectory>
</build>

Answer (score 0):

Try from command prompt, at trunk location of project.
share your pom.xml here. The info you have provided is vague to help.

Comment: First,install maven plugin in your eclipse. Try creating a sample maven project. If you see pom.xml in your sample project, maven plugin works.Now import your exisiting project as maven project.